# How to post an array of Json data in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here is my data

```
var sending files = 
[
{"filename": "manifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\extension\\manifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Fri Jul 24 10:44:50 2020", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Sat Jul 25 09:35:23 2020"}, 
{"filename": "manifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\fcm-extension-master\\fcm-extension-master\\manifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Sun Sep  2 22:52:18 2018", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Thu Jul 23 16:09:07 2020"},
{"filename": "manifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\fcm-javascript-master\\manifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Thu Jul 23 21:27:24 2020", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Thu Jul 23 21:29:09 2020"},
{"filename": "web-app-manifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\files required for vue working\\node_modules\\caniuse-db\\features-json\\web-app-manifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Sat Jan 25 15:38:44 2020", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Sat Oct 26 13:45:00 1985"},
{"filename": "AssetManifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\flutter apps\\myapp\\build\\app\\intermediates\\flutter\\debug\\flutter_assets\\AssetManifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Tue Jun 23 21:58:29 2020", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Tue Jun 23 21:58:29 2020"}, 
{"filename": "FontManifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\flutter apps\\myapp\\build\\app\\intermediates\\flutter\\debug\\flutter_assets\\FontManifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Tue Jun 23 21:58:29 2020", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Tue Jun 23 21:58:29 2020"}, 
{"filename": "AssetManifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\flutter apps\\myapp\\build\\app\\intermediates\\merged_assets\\debug\\out\\flutter_assets\\AssetManifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Tue Jun 23 21:58:35 2020", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Tue Jun 23 21:58:35 2020"}, 
{"filename": "FontManifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\flutter apps\\myapp\\build\\app\\intermediates\\merged_assets\\debug\\out\\flutter_assets\\FontManifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Tue Jun 23 21:58:35 2020", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Tue Jun 23 21:58:35 2020"},
{"filename": "manifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\my-extension\\manifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Fri Jul 24 21:54:59 2020", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Fri Jul 24 21:54:32 2020"}
]
```

I need to post this data to webserver from my flutter mobile app

Here is the code i tried

```
var response = await http.post(url,body:sendingFiles);
```

I also tried with `convert.jsonEncode(sendingFiles)`
if I use

```
var response = await http.post(url,body:convert.jsonEncode(sendingFiles));
```

I am getting the below output.

```
['{"filename":"FontManifest.json","filepath":"C:\\\\Users\\\\lenovo\\\\Desktop\\\\flutter apps\\\\myapp\\\\build\\\\app\\\\intermediates\\\\merged_assets\\\\debug\\\\out\\\\flutter_assets\\\\FontManifest.json"}', 
'{"filename":"manifest.json","filepath":"C:\\\\Users\\\\lenovo\\\\Desktop\\\\fcm-extension-master\\\\fcm-extension-master\\\\manifest.json"}', 
'{"filename":"web-app-manifest.json","filepath":"C:\\\\Users\\\\lenovo\\\\Desktop\\\\files required for vue working\\\\node_modules\\\\caniuse-db\\\\features-json\\\\web-app-manifest.json"}', 
'{"filename":"manifest.json","filepath":"C:\\\\Users\\\\lenovo\\\\Desktop\\\\fcm-javascript-master\\\\manifest.json"}'
]
```

Comment: you have to encode only the body json.encode(body)

Comment: You have to give server-side stack reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code.
You can use this code to pass the JSON body from the flutter request to the server. Also, you can pass you auth token (If you are using any).

```
Future<dynamic> getMillionDollarData(String token, String jsonBody) async {
 HttpClientRequest request = await client
    .postUrl(Uri.parse('server-url.com/someendpoint'));

 request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 request.headers.set('my-extra-token', token);

 HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

 request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonBody)));

 String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
 return json.decode(reply);
}
```

To receive JSON at the python server end

```
from flask import Flask, request

@app.route('/someendpoint'])
def someendpoint():
  data = request.json
```

Comment: I know how to post the data but data is not coming in the expected format.

Comment: Sorry my problem is with the file path, '\\' is converted to '\\\\' after json encode. Is there any solution for that

Comment: what technology you are using at the server side?

Comment: I am using flask to handle the post request.

Comment: The problem is {"filename": "manifest.json", "filepath": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\extension\\manifest.json", "fileCreationDate": "Fri Jul 24 10:44:50 2020", "fileLastModifiedDate": "Sat Jul 25 09:35:23 2020"}, 
Here in file path the double backslash in converted to four backslashes. so I think I will change the file path.